# How to make navigation links selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently added a navigation to a website. It's a fixed navbar with relevant links to the sections. It already contains a jquery script with a click event to make scrolling smooth. But I am having trouble with trying to add a selected class to the clicked link. I tried various answers in this site and in google with fail. It's a landing page which scrolls down to relevant block when the navbar links are clicked. :( 
Any help would be gladly appreciated. :-)

jQuery code I used...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".menu").click(function(event) {
   $(this).addClass("clicked");
   ---code to make smooth scroll-----
});
```

});

Comment: try to add css on active or visited
ask me if any query

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: I tried active and visited but failed.

Comment: I have noticed that the post is on-hold is there a way to close the question because I have got the correct answer. I am newbie here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu").click(function(event) {
     $(".clicked").removeClass("clicked");
     $(event.target).addClass("clicked");
      ---code to make smooth scroll-----
   });
});
```

Comment: This did work but every link gets the clicked class added when clicked on the rest of the links. Is there any way to add removeClass code to remove the class when clicked on another link.

Comment: Yes, just select the class before, look at the code that updated

Comment: Wow it worked perfectly!! Couldn't tackle this small problem since I am new to jQuery. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help. Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Unfortunately. I can't vote you because I am new to here and don't have a reputation more than 15. :(